# Count number of strings 'within' a string as part of a dplyr chain

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  x = 1:3,
  y = c('apples; pears', 'oranges; bananas; grapes', 'apples')
)

mydf
  x                        y
1 1            apples; pears
2 2 oranges; bananas; grapes
3 3                   apples
```

I would like the count of fruits in a new variable z. Desired outcome:

```
mydf
  x                        y z
1 1            apples; pears 2
2 2 oranges; bananas; grapes 3
3 3                   apples 1
```

Tried:

```
mydf %>% mutate(z = str_split(y, ';') %>% length) # gives '3' for all fields
```

How can I get the count of strings within a string by splitting on some character, in this case ';'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with `str_count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr0
mydf %>%
    mutate(z = str_count(y, '\\w+'))
```

---

The output of `str_split` is a `list` and `length` is the `length` of the whole list, we need `lengths` (returns the `length` of each `list` element)

```
mydf %>% 
   mutate(z = str_split(y, ';') %>% 
              lengths)
  x                        y z
1 1            apples; pears 2
2 2 oranges; bananas; grapes 3
3 3                   apples 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Remind me, what's `\\w+`?

Comment: @DougFir it is a for word

Comment: Dear akrun, How this function ```mutate(z = str_split(y, ';') %>% 
              lengths)``` would work with the new pipe operator?

Comment: @LDT You can use `mydf |> mutate(z = str_split(y, ';') |> lengths())`